# How to confirm a firm but set a function in-between?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I got a script that checks every form in my app and if there is one, that gets submitted, it will prevent the submission, toggles a loading screen and then submits the form.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

      const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
      forms.forEach((form) => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          document.getElementById('loading').classList.toggle('hidden');
          form.submit();
        })
      });

  });

</script>
```

This works perfectly but for some forms (like a deletion button) I want to ask to user if this is really what he wants to do:

```
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url('clients/' . $meeting->cid);?>" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
  <input type="hidden" name="delmeeting" value="<?=$meeting->id;?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="button">
</form>
```

This is in conflict with the first script. The alert gets shown correct but when I cancel it, the first script comes into place and submits.

How can I handle this?

What is important to me:

- display the loading div every time for each form
- having the possibility to have forms with and without a confirm window
- keeping the code small
- having individual texts for the confirm

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
forms.forEach((form) => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    if (form.onsubmit === null) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById('loading').classList.toggle('hidden');
      form.submit();
    }
  })
});
``
```